# std::unique analogue in Qt?

Tags: qt, sorting, stl, qt4, unique

I have browsed the documentation, but didn't find one.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just apply `std::unique` to the iterators of `QList`. `std::unique` just requires the iterators to be forward iterators ([here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique.html) and [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html)), and it appears that `QList`'s iterators meet that requirement.

Comment: well, it also requires compiling Qt with STL support (which so far wasn't needed)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a `QSet` instead (and use `QSet::toList` when you need it as a list).

Comment: set is good idea. The only reason I'm using list is that it's easier to add items (and there are thousands of them collected by a breath first search).

Comment: `mySet.insert(foo)` doesn't seem particularly hard to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I created my unique list of integers:

list=QSet::fromList(list).toList();

No need to add STD, it might not be the best way using very large integers though

Answer (score 0):

By now I have the following:

```
   //filter out duplicates: stl algorithm 'unique' would be useful here
      QList<int> uniqueIDs;
      qStableSort(res);
      foreach(int id, res)
       if ( (uniqueIDs.empty()) 
                || (uniqueIDs.back() != id))
            uniqueIDs.push_back(id);
      swap(res, uniqueIDs);
```

res being the input for filtering, and not pleased with it.